# Rを用いたデータの整理と生成

Tags: r, database

```
time data 
1 67
2 39

2000 45
```

time.csvというデータが有りますが（下参照）、2つ実現できないことがあって困っています。
1,R上で1～1500まで切り取って新しいデータセットを作る。
2,すでに推定の終わっているモデルを用いてdataの隣にpredictのデータを並べる。
（例） predict=3+time*1.4

一応いろいろ試してはいますがうまく行きません。
下のコードだとエラーが出てしまいます。

```
data <-read.csv("time.csv",header=TRUE)
pre<-data.frame(time=1：1500,data=data,predict=3+time*1.4)
```

EXCELだと簡単ですがRだとパッケージ分析ばかりやっていてクリーニングはEXCELにやらせていましたが、データが大きくなったり複雑になるとRのほうが楽だと思い今回質問させていただきました。RstudioやパッケージでSQLを使うという手もあるかと思いましたがRを用いる方向でお願い致します。

**結果**
1の方でとりあえずやってみましたが、

```
data <-read.csv("time.csv", header=TRUE)
pre<-data.frame(jikan=data$time[1:1000,],deeta=data$data[1:1000,])
Error in data$data[1:1000,]: incorrect number of dimensions
```

のようなエラーが出てしまいます。元データを見てもずれはないようですし、timeがintでdataがnumだったのをどちらもnumに揃えてもエラーが変わりません。
どこに問題があるのでしょうか？

**結果2**

```
> pre<-data.frame(jikan=data$time[1:1000],deeta=data$data[1:1000])
Error in data.frame(jikan = data$time[1:1000], deeta = data$data[1:1000]) : 
引数に異なる列数のデータフレームが含まれています: 0, 1000
```

と今度はエラーが出ました。どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか。

**追記**

```
> head(data,n=10)
  time data
1    1  7.8
2    2  5.6
3    3  5.1
4    4  7.3
5    5 10.8
6    6  6.2
7    7  5.2
8    8  5.5
9    9  5.7
10  10  6.3
```

です。

Comment: 1 ですが、`read.csv()` に `nrows` オプションをつけると良いですよ。 `data <-read.csv("time.csv",header=TRUE,nrows=1500)`

Comment: nrows=100

とすると上から100個分のみのデータが読み込まれるのですね。

Comment: nrowsは1～100だと使えそうですが250～400などの場合は使えそうにないですね。

Comment: 特定の列データは `vector` 型なので、`predicted<-data.frame(jikan=data$time[1:1000],deeta=data$data[1:1000])` とします(`,` は不要)。

Comment: `is.vector(data$time)` と `is.vector(data$data)` の結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: timeがFALSEでdataがTRUEでした。

Comment: 実際の `time.csv` ファイルの構造は回答欄に追記したものと同じでしょうか？

Comment: 1,2,3の順番で並んでいる列があり、そのとなりにデータが入っているという構造は同じです。

Comment: 差し支えなければ、先頭の10行程度を質問欄に追記していただけますか？

Comment: ええと、`time` 列がありませんが…。もしかして、`time` ではなくて `day` なのでしょうか？ その場合は、`pre <- data.frame(jikan=data$day[1:1000],deeta=data$data[1:1000])` となります。

Comment: すいません。写し間違えでした。TRUEになりました。

Comment: 質問欄も訂正させていただきました。

Comment: 無事一部の抽出が出来ました。お手数をお掛けして申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※ 質問欄に掲載されている `time.csv` ですが、スペース区切りに見えます。一応、以下の回答ではカンマ区切りを前提としています。

> 2,すでに推定の終わっているモデルを用いてdataの隣にpredictのデータを並べる。

`data` はデータフレームですので、列データに `$` でアクセスして `[1:1500]` で範囲を指定します。

```
data <-read.csv("time.csv", header=TRUE)
pre <- data.frame(data[1:1500,], predict=3+(data$time[1:1500])*1.4)
```

**追記**

質問欄の結果2について、こちらでの実行手順を以下に示します。

```
$ head time.csv
time,data
1,422
2,624
3,808
  :
1998,49
1999,628
2000,592

$ R --version
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"

$ R
> data <-read.csv("time.csv", header=TRUE)
> pre <- data.frame(jikan=data$time[1:1000],deeta=data$data[1:1000])
> head(pre)
  jikan deeta
1     1   422
2     2   624
3     3   808
4     4   888
5     5   484
6     6   739
> str(pre)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ jikan: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ deeta: int  422 624 808 888 484 739 357 677 588 907 ...
```

Comment: 質問欄のデータ例はわかりやすいようにスペース区切りで再現しましたが実際はカンマ区切りファイルです。
明日実行してみます。

Answer (score 1):

data.frameのサブセットは、以下のようにつくれます。

```
data_partial <- data[1:1500, ]
```

カラムの追加は以下のようにできます。毎回`data.frame()`で作り直す必要はありません。

```
data_partial$predict <- 3 + data_partial$time * 1.4
```

Comment: 正直、このあたりはかなり基礎的な内容なので、ここでつまづくようであれば思い切って初心者向けのRの本でも買って勉強しなおされることをオススメします。「みんなのR」なんかがいい本だと思います。